# How to join split clips back in iMovie?

Tags: imovie

After I split clip, now I have two parts of one clip. However my split was very useful, now I prefer to join it back, but my option to join clips is greyed out. Why?

[image]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315957/imovie-join-clips-option-greyed-out?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

In order to join clips you will need to hold down shift and click on the two clips you want to join, making sure that both clips are highlighted in yellow (I am using iMovie on Yosemite). See attached photo.

[image: Yellow Highlighted Around Clips]

Comment: Um, then what? Shift-clicking two clips just selects them.

Comment: Then go to the modify menu and click join clips. The reason the join clips choice was grey in the initial question was due to not having both clips selected.

Comment: Join Clips is still greyed out for me even though I select both clips.  What other reasons are there for both clips being greyed?